# instanceof doesn't work with "or"

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, deserialization, instanceof

I'm working on a web project with Java.

My colleague has finished the socket part, including object serialization and deserialization.

What I need to do is to develop the classes that would be serialized and deserialized to send and receive them.

The sequence diagram is simple:

- the client sends a string to the server
- the server create an object with the received string
- the server sends the object to the client

I have now two kinds of objects:

```
class T1{public int i1 = 1;}
class T2{public int i2 = 2;}
//both classes have implemented Serializable and override toString
```

And I do things as below:

```
Object obj = class.forName(strFromClient).newInstance();
if(obj instanceof T1 || obj instanceof T2)
{
    // send obj to client with my colleague's method
    send(obj);
}
```

The client can receive successfully the obj of type of `T1`, the client can `System.out.println(obj)` and get `1`.
To my surprise, when I do the same thing for `T2`, it doesn't work. When the client try to `System.out.println(obj)`, a `0` is shown whereas I'm expecting a `2`. I also try to add a `String` into T2 and the client get an `NullException`, meaning that the string in the received obj is `null`.

I don't quite understand why but if I change my code like this, everything will be fine:

```
Object obj = class.forName(strFromClient).newInstance();
if(obj instanceof T1)
{
    // send obj to client with my colleague's method
    send(obj);
}
else if(obj instanceof T2)
{
    // send obj to client with my colleague's method
    send(obj);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a simple test and writing something like `Object obj = new T2();  if(obj instanceof T1 || obj instanceof T2) ... [etc]`

Comment: have you printed `strFromClient` and make sure this is actually what you expect it to be?

Comment: Also, since this appears the be impossible, can you provide the full implementation of `T1` and `T2` so we can see if maybe something other is overwriting the value you expect it to have?

Comment: Use System.out.println(obj.getI1()) obj is instance of T1 and obj.getI2() if obj is instance of T2

Comment: The problem lies in code that you have not yet shown us. Can you provide a minimal snippet that actually demonstrates your problem? Our efforts to do so have demonstrated no problem.

Comment: @B.Dalton  I'll update my question in two hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a test using the following code:

```
Object x = 1; // afterwards = ""

if (x instanceof String || x instanceof Integer) {
    System.out.println("Hurray!");
}
```

In both cases: `x = 1` or  `x = ""` the string `Hurray!` was printed. Hence I guess your `obj` is neither of type `T1` nor of type `T2`.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is  - T1 and T2 value you receive there are null ,

in only that case the condition will not get validated .

Please debug and check the value of T1 and T2 you receive in the step.

You can use this code - and add null checks before instance of

Comment: His issue is that the `instanceof` statement evaluates to `true`, but the value of the instance is wrong. If the values were `null`, the if statement would evaluate to `false` and nothing would be sent.